# Что: Can it even be translated?

Tags: грамматика, значения

This word has given me a lot of trouble while studying Russian. At first, I thought it meant "what" or "that". But, I recently heard someone say, "Да, что очень важно." Why? Why not, "Это очень важно"? Then, I heard someone say, "Есть что посмотреть." What? Does this word mean what, that, thing? I just need a list of uses for this word because it is just not clicking for me.

Comment: Tried to look in the dictionary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The list is very long and I am afraid it still doesn't comprise all the meanings,because there are lots of idioms.The main points are

1.*Что* as a question word and a conjunction is used to speak of an inanimate thing, an action

> Что такое? Я вижу, что происходит. Что случилось?

2.As a conjunction (when unstressed ) in subordinate clauses.

> Я знаю, что он был здесь.

3.Meaning "how much?"(colloquial )

> Купите яблоки.– Что стОит?

4.Meaning "something "

> А было ли что на самом деле?

5.Meaning "why" (colloquial )

> Что же ты ничего не сказал?

6 Meaning "как" in a comparison

> Материнский гнев — что весенний снег: и много его выпадет, да скоро растает.

7 Emphatic

> Что, я неправ?

8 Meaning "which, that"

> Дом, что стоит на углу, покосился.

9.Surprise

> Что вы говорите? Вот не знал.

10 As a question to a predicate describing a state of things.

> Что наш больной? Ему легче?

11.Meaning "it doesn't matter "

> Что мне дождь, что мне зной, что мне дождик проливной, когда мои друзья со мной.
>   Неприятности что, справимся. Что толку спорить? Что пользы ждать.

Idioms and phrases.

> и что,
>   не весть что,
>   не для чего,
>   чего ради,
>   чем бы ни,
>   чему быть, того не миновать,
>   подумать бог знает что,
>   что бы ни,
>   что бы там ни было,
>   что же, что ж,
>   что ли,
>   что нибудь,
>   что такое,
>   не что иное, как,
>   что угодно,
>   все что угодно.

Comment: Есть что посмотреть –There's something to see. Да, что очень важно.– Yes, which is important.

Answer (score 3):

The incomplete phrase <**Да, что очень важно.**> can have one of two meanings, depending on context:

1. It can be a concluding reply to another person's words, then it means:

> *Yes, **which** is very important.*

2. It can precede something the speaker wants to add to what he/she's just said, then it means:

> *Oh/Well, and here's **what**'s very important.*

**Да** doesn't translate literally here.

Comment: I don't agree with the second. This isn't possible here. Да, что очень важно. would mean only Yes, which is very important. Even if we continue the sentence.

Comment: Why 'even'? In that case something _always_ follows it. **Да [кстати, чуть не забыл], [вот] что очень важно. Возьмите с собой паспорт.**

Comment: Here's an example of it in living language: https://market.yandex.ru/product--Sony-NWZ-E436F/3528479/reviews _... ах да, что очень важно и я почти забыл, это время работы без подзаряда..._

Comment: One more example. _Да, что очень важно - перед отелем есть паркинг с круглосуточным видеонаблюдением._ http://www.welcome2bg.com/articles/113

Answer (score 3):

Some words could be omitted:
"Да, (это то) что очень важно."
"Есть что (-нибудь) посмотреть?"
"Есть (кое-) что посмотреть!" - "There is something to watch down here!"

Comment: How about "Да, есть что посмотреть" - "Yeh, there's a big selection here" (video)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it always means `what`.

Your example `Есть что посмотреть` could still make sense in English as:

```
What is there to watch?
```

Comment: You are absolutely wrong